# How to share ar content from one device to another?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a scenario where I need to share ar content from one device to another which is located remotely (not at same location).

How can I share the ar content from one device to another.
I am trying with arkit, unity3d

I tried https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/build-shared-ar-with-twilio-video-arkit-and-data-track.html

but from this, sharing of ar content in unidirectional, I need bidirectional.

Need your valuable input.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `content`? A file, a value, a rendered frame, mesh data, object positions ...?

Comment: 'content' means if I create a `3d drawing` like this one `https://github.com/laanlabs/ARBrush` that drawing I need to share with the remote device and vice-versa.

Comment: I went to that page and didn't see any drawing ... I guess however that drawing "knows" it's line points so you can simply share them on the network to regenerate the drawing somewhere else.

Comment: `https://github.com/laanlabs/ARBrush/blob/master/anim.gif` see this, do you know any sample to share it with network